# jQuery animate().delay().animate() am I doing this right?

Tags: jquery

Hi getting variable peformance & effect between firefox (pretty bad) chrome (ok)
Sometimes this doesn't do the first animation, and sometimes it gets stuck.

Have I structured this right?

```
$notification.animate({
    top: '-=' + ($notification.outerHeight() + 20)
    }, 1500, function() {
        $(this).delay(2000);
        $(this).animate({
            top: '+=' + ($notification.outerHeight() + 20)
        }, 1500, function() {

    });
});
```

Comment: No idea. What exactly are you asking? Could you post a sample page showing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$notification
    .animate({
        top: '-=' + ($notification.outerHeight() + 20)
    }, 1500)
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({
        top: '+=' + ($notification.outerHeight() + 20)
    }, 1500);
```

EDIT: fiddle at  http://zequinha-bsb.int-domains.com/notification.html

Comment: While there's nothing with what you've suggested I'm inclined to think that wasn't his intention. As you can see he's attempting this on a notification which implies he wants the user to read something. Using your approach the user would have half a second to read the notification before the second animation triggers. I believe he wanted to give the users two seconds to read the notification.

Comment: The code serves the intention of displaying the notification for 2 seconds. The `delay` function delays the execution of subsequent items in the queue. So this code would animate for 1.5 seconds, wait 2 seconds, then animate again for 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! I like your layout nice neat:O)

Comment: @Nathan - Oh I had no idea jQuery behaved like that. My mistake. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$notification.animate({
    top: '-=' + ($notification.outerHeight() + 20)
    }, 1500, function() {
        $(this).delay(2000).animate({
            top: '+=' + ($notification.outerHeight() + 20)
        }, 1500, function() {

    });
});
```